# How to exclude locked files or folders In an AppleScript that selects all files in a particular folder

Tags: finder, applescript

Here's my situation. I created an AppleScript for cleaning up my desktop.  It essentially selects all files and folders on my desktop, creates a new folder with a specific name and date format, and moves all the files from my desktop to the new folder.  This script works beautifully until I realized that occasionally there were files or folders I wanted to remain on my desktop.  My solution was to open the get info window for each file or folder that I wanted to remain on my desktop, and select the “lock” option in the get info window.

My problem is now because of the locked files, the script cannot completely execute without displaying an error message.  If I click “OK” on the error message, the script will finish and move every file with the exception of the ones that are locked.

I would prefer not to have to go through this extra step by clicking the okay button.  I tried adding some system event actions to the script to automatically click the “ok” button and that did not work.

I'm starting to think that the only real solution would be to not select those locked files or folders in the first place.  This is where I am lost.  Can anyone help direct me as to how to avoid selecting the locked files in the first place?

[image]

---

Here is the script in its entirety.

---

```
set scriptPath to (load script file "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~ScriptEditor2:Documents:Cleanup Desktop.scptd:Contents:Resources:Scripts:Current Time A.M. P.M. And Short Date.scpt")

tell scriptPath
    timeandDate() -- This will get the time and date in this format "05/31/2017 @ 9:10:48 PM" called from the loaded script file above
end tell

set timeandDate to the result -- This will copy the time and date results from the previous step and and set it as this new variable

tell application "Finder"
    if running then
        close every window
        activate
        make new Finder window
        set target of Finder window 1 to folder "Desktop" of folder "Smokestack" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    end if
    open Finder window 1
    activate
end tell

delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    key code 0 using (command down) -- This will select all files and folders on the desktop in the active finder window
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    set these_items to the selection
    set destinationFolder to make new folder at POSIX file "/Users/Smokestack/Jimz_Important_Stuff/Desktop_Cleanups/" with properties {name:timeandDate}
    move these_items to destinationFolder
    reveal destinationFolder
end tell
```

Here is a revised version of the script without calling handlers from external files

```
on timeandDate()
    set CurrentTime to (time string of (current date))
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
    set theLongDate to (current date)
    set theLongDate to (date string of theLongDate)
    set currentMonth to (word 1 of text item 2 of theLongDate)
    set currentDay to (word 2 of text item 2 of theLongDate)
    set currentYear to (word 1 of text item 3 of theLongDate)
    set monthList to {January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December}
    repeat with x from 1 to 12
        if currentMonth = ((item x of monthList) as string) then
            set theRequestNumber to (text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & x))
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    set currentMonth to theRequestNumber
    set currentDay to (text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & currentDay))
    set theShortDate to (currentMonth & "/" & currentDay & "/" & currentYear) as string
    set CurrentTime to (time string of (current date))
    set CurrentTimeandShortDate to (theShortDate & " @ " & CurrentTime)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
end timeandDate

timeandDate()

set timeandDate to the result

tell application "Finder"
    close every window
    activate
    make new Finder window
    set target of Finder window 1 to folder "Desktop" of folder "Smokestack" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    select every file of the front Finder window 
    delay 1
    set these_items to the selection
    set destinationFolder to make new folder at POSIX file "/Users/Smokestack/Jimz_Important_Stuff/Desktop_Cleanups/" with properties {name:timeandDate}
    try
        move these_items to destinationFolder
    end try
    reveal destinationFolder
end tell
```

After making some revisions to the script, as long as the locked items on my desktop are only folders and not files, now this script works beautifully.  However it will still generate an error if there are any individual locked files.

Comment: Thank you for your Insights.  Very good points on your Finder Comments and I will make changes in the script. Thank you

Comment: Is there possibly a way we can use a shorter command something like...  tell application "Finder" to set selection to every file whose properties is equal to {locked:false}  <-----  I've tried about 20 different variations of that with no success

Comment: So I should add set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "" At the end of the timeandDate()  handler, just before the end timeandDate? Or do I add it to the main body of my script itself, after i call the handler?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59709/discussion-between-user3439894-and-wch1zpink).

Comment: I've updated my answer and would like you to test the new _code_ and suggest you use it over the other example _code_.

Comment: Your final version of the code is lightning fast and much more streamlined.  Excellent job Master... This grasshoppa has much to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** As I mentioned somewhere in the comments that I'd build out a 10.12.5 system this past weekend and do some testing, I did.

Here is what I found out:

- The code of my answer, inclusive of edit 5 on Jun 2 at 15:34, works on my system without issue.
- After a review of all *code* and comments, it dawned on me that while my *code*, as is, worked on my system and I gave note referencing the `delay` *command* having to adjust *values* and or add/remove as/if necessary, etc., **that this mainly comes down to timing issues and the pitfalls of that particular form of event coding.**

Therefore, and while I'll leave the original answer at the bottom of this update, I decided to look at this from a different programatic angle and offer the following *code* as a better way to code this *script* to accomplish the task at hand.

This new *code*, does not rely on closing opened **Finder** *windows* and then opening a **Finder** *window* to the **Desktop** *folder* of the **User** to then have **System Events** select all *items* in the *target folder*, or the use of the `delay` *command* to deal with timing issues etc. All of which I personally don't like, because I don't want all **Finder** *windows* I have opened, closed to accomplish a task such as this. Or code it to leave the existing *windows* opened while ensuring the **Finder** *window* of the **Desktop** *folder* within the **Home** *folder* is the *topmost* **Finder** *window* to ensure **System Events** *selects* the correct *items* and get the timings right, etc.!

The following **AppleScript** *code* offers a more safe and faster way to accomplish the task at hand and I encourage you to use it over the previous *code* examples.

Note: With the previous caveats in play, (the existence of the folder the destination folder is created in, etc.), you should not not need to modify this *code* and should be able to use it **as is**. That is to say, you're certainly free to modify the *code* anyway you need/want, but **as is**, it should work.

**New AppleScript *code*:**

```
tell current application
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            if running then
                set theseFileSystemObjects to (get every item of (path to desktop))
                set theFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to {}
                repeat with i from 1 to (count of theseFileSystemObjects)
                    set thisFileSystemObject to (item i of theseFileSystemObjects)
                    if not locked of (get properties of thisFileSystemObject) then
                        set end of theFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to thisFileSystemObject
                    end if
                end repeat
                if theFileSystemObjectsNotLocked is not equal to {} then
                    tell current application to set theDateTimeNow to ¬
                        (do shell script "date '+%m.%d.%Y @ %I.%M.%S %p'") as string
                    set theDestinationFolder to make new folder at ¬
                        ((path to home folder as string) & "Jimz_Important_Stuff:Desktop_Cleanups:") with properties {name:theDateTimeNow}
                    move theFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to theDestinationFolder
                    open theDestinationFolder
                    activate theDestinationFolder
                end if
            else
                tell current application
                    activate
                    display dialog "Finder is not currently running!" & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                        "Open Finder, then run Desktop Clean Up again." buttons {"OK"} ¬
                        default button 1 with title "Desktop Clean Up"
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
    on error eStr number eNum
        activate
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Desktop Clean Up" with icon caution
        return
    end try
end tell
```

---

**Original Answer:**

This is an example of how I'd write the entire *script* to be *run*, as is, as either a *.scpt* file or an *.app* file, on your system. I'm saying *your system*, because the *target destination folder* is set for your system.

There is no need to *load* an *outside resource* and no *handler* to *set* the *value* of the *variable* used for *the destination folder name*. I choose to use a `do shell script` *command* for that, using the `date` *command* to return a *custom date time string variable*, as it's one line of *code* compared to the amount of *code* in the `on timeandDate()` *handler*, and it returns the same *pattern*.

I will continue to use this on my system with appropriately adjusted pathnames and a different *pattern* for *the destination folders name*, replacing the `/` and `:` with `.` in the *custom date time string variable* used in *the destination folder name*.

As coded, this first version of the *script* moves all *file system objects*, that are **not** locked, currently in the *Desktop folder* to the *destination folder*. The *script* includes minimal appropriate *error handling* and as coded you shouldn't have the issues you were previously having. This of course assumes that the `$HOME/Jimz_Important_Stuff/Desktop_Cleanups` folder exists. If not, you'll get the appropriate error message, however additional *error handling* could be added to create the hierarchical folded structure as/if necessary.

This first *script* should resolve all issues you are/were having with your own *code* and IMO is a better way to code it then just trapping and eating the error with just a `try` *statement* alone, because as coded, it can only move files that are **not** locked and doesn't even try to move a locked file.

This was tested under macOS 10.12.3 and should work for you on macOS 10.12.5, which you're presently running.

**AppleScript *Code*:**

---

```
tell current application
    try
        set theDateTimeNow to (do shell script "date '+%m/%d/%Y @ %I:%M:%S %p'") as string
        tell application "Finder"
            if running then
                close every window
                set target of (make new Finder window) to (path to desktop)
                activate
                delay 0.5
                tell application "System Events" to key code 0 using {command down}
                delay 0.5
                set theseFileSystemObjects to the selection
                set theDestinationFolder to make new folder at ¬
                    ((path to home folder as string) & "Jimz_Important_Stuff:Desktop_Cleanups:") with properties {name:theDateTimeNow}
                set theListOfFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to {}
                repeat with i from 1 to (count of theseFileSystemObjects)
                    set thisFileSystemObject to (item i of theseFileSystemObjects)
                    if not locked of thisFileSystemObject then
                        set end of theListOfFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to thisFileSystemObject
                    end if
                end repeat
                move theListOfFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to theDestinationFolder
                reveal theDestinationFolder
            else
                tell current application
                    activate
                    display dialog "Finder is not currently running!" & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                        "Open Finder, then run Desktop Clean Up again." buttons {"OK"} ¬
                        default button 1 with title "Desktop Clean Up" with icon caution
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
    on error eStr number eNum
        activate
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Desktop Clean Up" with icon caution
        return
    end try
end tell
```

Note: As to the *value* of the `delay` *commands*, they may need to be adjusted for your system and or additional ones added as/if necessary and or removed if not needed. As presently coded, this *script* worked without issue, dozens of times in testing on my system, with varying counts and sizes of *file system objects* being acted upon in the *Desktop folder*. Make any adjustments as necessary.

The *file system objects* tested were, *files*, *folders*, *aliases*, *symlinks*, *application bundles* and *document bundles*, the latter two of which are just *folders*. These FSOs were of various sizes, both locked and **not** locked.

---

This second version of the *script* goes beyond your expressed needs and makes a duplicate of the locked *file system objects* currently in the *Desktop folder* to the *destination folder*, while reseting the locked flag on the duplicates so they can be deleted without raising a flag at the time you may choose to delete them. I'm including it as it may have added value and you find it useful.

**AppleScript *Code*:**

---

```
tell current application
    try
        set theDateTimeNow to (do shell script "date '+%m/%d/%Y @ %I:%M:%S %p'") as string
        tell application "Finder"
            if running then
                close every window
                set target of (make new Finder window) to (path to desktop)
                activate
                delay 0.5
                tell application "System Events" to key code 0 using {command down}
                delay 0.5
                set theseFileSystemObjects to the selection
                set theDestinationFolder to make new folder at ¬
                    ((path to home folder as string) & "Jimz_Important_Stuff:Desktop_Cleanups:") with properties {name:theDateTimeNow}
                set theListOfFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to {}
                set theListOfLockedFileSystemObjects to {}
                repeat with i from 1 to (count of theseFileSystemObjects)
                    set thisFileSystemObject to (item i of theseFileSystemObjects)
                    if not locked of thisFileSystemObject then
                        set end of theListOfFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to thisFileSystemObject
                    else
                        set end of theListOfLockedFileSystemObjects to thisFileSystemObject
                    end if
                end repeat
                move theListOfFileSystemObjectsNotLocked to theDestinationFolder
                duplicate theListOfLockedFileSystemObjects to theDestinationFolder
                repeat with i from 1 to (count of theListOfLockedFileSystemObjects)
                    set thisFileSystemObject to (item i of theListOfLockedFileSystemObjects)
                    set locked of alias ((theDestinationFolder as string) & name of thisFileSystemObject) to false
                end repeat
                reveal theDestinationFolder
            else
                tell current application
                    activate
                    display dialog "Finder is not currently running!" & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                        "Open Finder, then run Desktop Clean Up again." buttons {"OK"} ¬
                        default button 1 with title "Desktop Clean Up" with icon caution
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
    on error eStr number eNum
        activate
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Desktop Clean Up" with icon caution
        return
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: Okay I ran this first version of your script several times and each time and scripteditor, It threw an error message

tell application "Script Editor"
 display dialog "The folder “” can’t be moved into itself. number -122" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon caution
  --> {button returned:"OK"}
end tell

Comment: Running this second version of the script I got the same error message… I think it maybe because on my desktop I have mounted Macintosh HD, Boot Camp, and two separate time capsules. Once the script throws the error, I look at my desktop and every single item is selected including those mounted driveS

Comment: In finder preferences I chose not to show those mounted drives on the desktop and then I ran the script and it ran beautifully.  If you can figure out a way to exclude the mounted drives from being selected in the script, you would be a mad genius LOL

Comment: @wch1zpink, If the first vision is having an issue the second version isn't going to fix it. Without seeing your full logs it's going to be a bit harder to diagnose the issue. I'd say test with replacing the `/` and `:` with `.` in the `do shell script "date ..."` _command_, so as to avoid any issue in the naming convention.  Also, it would be good to see the output of `ls -al@ "$HOME/Desktop/"` with devices showing. Mounted devices, while they appear on the Desktop of the Display, they don't exist in `$HOME/Desktop` folder and that should have no bearing on the functionality of the script!

Comment: @wch1zpink, Obviously there is something quite different between my system and yours, but what!? This weekend I'll try to make time to setup a 10.12.5 system and see if I can reproduce the issue. A workaround option might be to programmatically, if possible, toggle the flag(s) that show/hide external devices..., move the target files, and toggle the flag(s) again. (That is, if you what those devices to always show.) I'll look at that, but I'd like to be able to reproduce your issue and then code appropriately for it vs. a workaround.

Comment: BINGO!! If you substitute the "Tell Finder" part of your code with this.. tell application "Finder" if running then close every window activate make new Finder window set target of Finder window 1 to folder "Desktop" of folder "Smokestack" of folder "Users" of startup disk delay 1 tell application "System Events" to key code 0 using {command down} delay 0.5  It solves all problems!! At least on my system

Comment: @wch1zpink, Adjusting the _value_ of a `delay` can be critical in some cases. `0.5` works for me but having to set it to `1` or even a bit higher is no big deal, it takes the _delay_ it needs! :) If I run in Script Editor, by itself, `tell application "Finder" to set target of (make new Finder window) to (path to desktop)` it opens a new Finder window at my Desktop and shows only the _file system objects_ that are actually in my `$HOME/Desktop` folder, no mounted internal/external devices even though they show on the Desktop of the Display (as they should with the Finder preference set).

Comment: @wch1zpink, You should not have to change `set target of (make new Finder window) to (path to desktop)` to two separate _commands_ e.g. `make new Finder window` and `set target of Finder window 1 to folder "Desktop" of folder "Smokestack" of folder "Users" of startup disk`, that's what the single line of my _code_ does on every major version I tested  on from  OS X 10.8.6, 10.9., 10.10, 10.11.6 and macOS 10.12.3. I can believe it's not working in 10.12.5, but I'm going to check it out this weekend.

Comment: Bottom line is, if you adjust my _code_, however necessary to get the job done without issue, that's what's important! :) Glad I could help!

Comment: I just tried running your code again, without my edits.  I adjusted your delay values several different times.  It still draws an error.  What it actually does is it actually selects all of the files directly on my desktop but it also opens  a finder window showing the desktop folder but refuses to select the items in the finder window.  So strange.  But either way, KUDOS to you with your version.  Thanks a lot +1 and accepted

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be to put some of your code into a `try` block and also use `on error` to ignore that specific error message, but to still display a message if it encounters a different error instead.

The advantage of this approach is that you're not telling your script to ignore all errors, just in case something else occurs and you should be aware of it.

In order to achieve this, try the following:

```
set scriptPath to (load script file "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~ScriptEditor2:Documents:Cleanup Desktop.scptd:Contents:Resources:Scripts:Current Time A.M. P.M. And Short Date.scpt")

tell scriptPath
    timeandDate() -- This will get the time and date in this format "05/31/2017 @ 9:10:48 PM" called from the loaded script file above
end tell

set timeandDate to the result -- This will copy the time and date results from the previous step and and set it as this new variable

tell application "Finder"
    if running then
        close every window
        activate
        make new Finder window
        set target of Finder window 1 to folder "Desktop" of folder "Smokestack" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    end if
    open Finder window 1
    activate
end tell

delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    key code 0 using (command down) -- This will select all files and folders on the desktop in the active finder window
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    try
        set these_items to the selection
        set destinationFolder to make new folder at POSIX file "/Users/Smokestack/Jimz_Important_Stuff/Desktop_Cleanups/" with properties {name:timeandDate}
        move these_items to destinationFolder
        reveal destinationFolder
    on error error_message number error_number
        if the error_number is not -50 then
            display dialog error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        end if
    end try

end tell
```

Now, you'll see that I've placed the second block of `tell application "Finder"` code within a `try` block (you'll notice the use of `try` and `end try`. And, within that block I've inserted the following code:

```
    on error error_message number error_number
    if the error_number is not -50 then
        display dialog error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    end if
```

Basically, this *should* have the effect of telling the script that in the event of a Finder error of -50 to just ignore it, but if it's not -50 then display the error. (I'm assuming that this is the error your script gets - if not you can just replace the `-50` with the correct error number.

Obviously I can't test this at my end, so please let me know how you go.

Comment: I couldn't replicate wch1zpink's exact error message, but I agree with your answer... using appropriate error handling. +1

Comment: @Monomeeth I ran your version of the code and saved it as an application and it produced the exact same error message